# CodeIgniter - Load language globally (not by file but by folder)

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

**Now:**

In the config file you can set a default language:

```
$config['language'] = 'german';
```

Every loaded language file is now loaded from the 'german' folder

```
$this->lang->load('custom_messages');
echo $this->lang->line('hello');          //prints "hallo"
```

It's easy to change languages locally via

```
$this->lang->load('custom_messages', 'english');
echo $this->lang->line('hello');          //prints "hello"
```

**Wish:**

But I want to change the language system wide (language selection at login) like the config file does. So I don't have to to load every _lang-File one by one with the correct language attribute.

Pseudo-Code (config language -> german)

```
$this->lang->set('english');
$this->lang->load('custom_messages');
echo $this->lang->line('hello');          //should print "hello"
```

There is nothing documented for this (in my opinion common) use-case.

This doesn't work:

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'english');
```

Comment: changing it before loading language files should work; Have you tried calling set_item before loading the translation files or after?

Comment: Good hint, but I call set_item before loading. To be sure I added log_messages() which proved it. Any other ideas?
Of course, as a "not so elegant" workaround I could save the chosen language in $_SESSION and always call `$this->lang->load(file, session->lang );` but as the config is capable of setting a whole language as default, I would find that more sophisticated.

Comment: So, do you mean that set_item isn't allowing you to set the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this locally, and it appears that you can change the language using set_item but you'll have to do this before loading the language file.

You can do this in constructor, save current language name in a session then set it in constructor

```
public function __construct () {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->config->set_item('language', $this->session->userdata('current_language'));  
}
```

here's my test controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->config->item('language')); // english
        $this->config->set_item('language', 'german');
        var_dump($this->config->item('language')); // german
        $this->lang->load('test');
        var_dump($this->lang->line('something')); // german translated line
    }
```